# CoreData Abstract entity with relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, relationship

I have this situation:

I have two CoreData entities:

**MUSIC_ACTIVITY** is an ABSTRACT CoreData entity;

**LOCATION**: with some attributes as: city, address,...

**BAR**: with some attributes;
**PUB**: with some attributes;

in *MUSIC_ACTIVITY* I have a relationship with *LOCATION* (1to1).

*MUSIC_ACTIVITY* is the PARENT entity of *BAR*;
*MUSIC_ACTIVITY* is the PARENT entity of *PUB*;

I generate automatically class of this model..
So:
In *MUSIC_ACTIVITY* I have one property *LOCATION*
In *LOCATION* I have property *MUSIC_ACTIVITY* (inverse)

How can I access to *LOCATION* information into *BAR* and *PUB* entity ?

for example: I declarated the relationship with LOCATION using 'address' (like name). So in MUSIC_ACTIVITY I have a property address (LOCATION type).
In PUB I need to overwrite the init..for example:

```
-(id) initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (self) {
        self.name = @"MY NAME";
        self.address = .... ///ERROR ////
    }
    return self;
}
```

but I can't use self.address ...

Comment: Same way you'd access the properties of a parent class in a subclass instance.  `myBar.location.address` or whatever.  Is there some code you have that's not working?

Comment: This work if the parentEntity is not a abstract entity. What is the best way in this case? Having the parent as abstract or no?

Comment: Works for me, which is why I asked if you have some code that's not working.   Make sure the inheritance in your data model is what you expect-- you can change the outline style in XCode to "hierarchical" as well as verifying the parent entity.

Comment: ok, I added an simple example..please see my edit..

Comment: ok, I solved .. I regenerated my class model .. probably I not had : MUSIC_ACTIVITY as subclass. Thanks. If you want add an answer, I can set your suggestion as answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access parent entity's attributes the same as you would the properties of a parent class.

Just some debugging tips for entity inheritance in XCode:

- Double check the parent entity
- Change the outline style of the xcdatamodel viewer to hierarchical

I also recommend MOGenerator.  You don't have to manually recreate the backing class definitions when you change the model.