# Parent-Child Hierarchy in NSManagedObject CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, entity-framework, core-data

In the xcdatamodeld file, I created a `Person` entity with `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` fields. Then I created a `User` entity with an extra field in it. I set `Person` as the parent entity of `User`.

Then I used 'Create NSManagedObject Subclass...' option from the 'Editor' menu and generated classes for these entities.

Now when I did `User* user = [[User alloc] init]`, I could not access `user.firstName` or other properties of the superclass `Person` for some reason. It said, "Property firstName was not found on object of type User*"

When I checked, the generated `User` class was a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and not `Person`. I thought this was a problem, and changed `User` to be a subclass of `Person`. The code compiled fine, but crashed at runtime with this error --

```
2014-11-05 20:24:14.142 MyApp[15131:3332646] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'User' 
2014-11-05 20:24:14.142 MyApp[15131:3332646] -[User setFirstName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee5a436b90
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong here. I thought Xcode is supposed to generate the classes correctly and I should be able to use them out of the box.

Comment: I, [and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703485/coredata-abstract-entity-with-relationship/) have found it easy to somehow not have the parent entity stick in the XCode GUI.  Simply setting the parent entity as Person should be enough to access user.firstName.   You can also query user.entity.superEntity.name or some other such path to check inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the failed initialisation (the first error in the list) is the cause of the second error (unrecognised selector).

You need to use `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` rather than just `init`.  Or alternatively use `NSEntityDescription`'s 
`insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` class method.

Comment: Yes. I realized that after a couple of hours. That was the problem.